# Get rid of these 3 Cocos2D analyzer warnings?

Tags: ios, null, cocos2d-iphone, warnings, analyzer

I hate warnings anywhere in my app so I fixed all of the other Cocos2D analyzer warnings except these three which I do not know how to solve.

Anyway, hopefully somewhat here can help me resolve these 3 warnings! **The line with the warning is the one with the comment before it saying "This Line"**

***One*** Function call argument is an uninitialized value

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)time
{
    int i, j;

    Tile *tileArray = (Tile*)tiles;

    for( i = 0; i < gridSize_.x; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < gridSize_.y; j++ )
        {
            //This Line tileArray->position = ccpMult( ccp(tileArray->delta.x, tileArray->delta.y), time);
            [self placeTile:ccg(i,j) tile:*tileArray];
            tileArray++;
        }
    }
}
```

***Two*** The left operand of '*' is a garbage value

```
// color
                p->color.r += (p->deltaColor.r * dt);
                p->color.g += (p->deltaColor.g * dt);
                //This Line p->color.b += (p->deltaColor.b * dt);
                p->color.a += (p->deltaColor.a * dt);
```

***Three*** Assigned value is garbage or undefined

```
void cc_pointerswap(void* a, void* b, size_t width)
{
    void* tmp;
    tmp = *(void**)a;
   //This Line *(void**)a = *(void**)b;
    *(void**)b = tmp;
}
```